# quartz job run only once

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have created Job. I want to run it every minute 
but it run only once.
following is my java class

```
String exp = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";

            SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(schedulartest.class).build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                                            .startNow()
                                            .withSchedule(
                                                 CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(exp))
                                            .build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

when i execute it it run only first time.
can someone help to figure out these

Comment: Not familiar with quartz-scheduler, but if I were making that library, "startNow" would well, start it now.  I'm guessing it doesn't take the schedule since it has already started and default schedule is to launch once.  Try switching around startNow and withSchedule?

Comment: @Neil i have to run schedular every minute.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it :

```
 CronScheduleBuilder cronSchedule = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule( "* * * * * ?" );
 Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity( "trigger-" + id, group ).withSchedule( cronSchedule ).build();    
 scheduler.scheduleJob( job, trigger );
```